# Medoo - Updating table row matching multiple field

Tags: php, medoo

I am using Medoo. the update below works fine with single field match. I want to update data if match with clientId and businessCity.

```
$database->update("clientInfo", array(
     "businessName" => $_POST['businessName'],
     "contactName" => $_POST['contactName'],
     "businessEmail" => $_POST['businessEmail'],
     "businessPhone" => $_POST['businessPhone'],
     "businessWebsite" => $_POST['businessWebsite'],
     "businessAddress" => $_POST['businessAddress'],
     "businessAddress2" => $_POST['businessAddress2'],
     "businessCity" => $_POST['businessCity'],
     "businessState" => $_POST['businessState'],
     "businessZip" => $_POST['businessZip']
), array(
    "clientId" => $_POST['clientId'],
    "businessCity" => $_POST['businessCity'],
));
```

I tried like this. but not working for me.

Comment: are u using medoo OR cakephp ? bcoz it does not seem to be cakephp UPDATE

Comment: Sorry i'm using medoo.

Comment: Hi Why didn't go for cakePHP , Do u think medoo Is better ? :) haha

Answer (score 1):

`echo $database->last_query();`

use this function to check out the SQL query performed for debug.

Answer (score 1):

Read about the Relativity Condition from Medoo documentation: http://medoo.in/api/where

Just add `AND` connector to each value.

```
$database->update("clientInfo", array(
     "businessName" => $_POST['businessName'],
     "contactName" => $_POST['contactName'],
     "businessEmail" => $_POST['businessEmail'],
     "businessPhone" => $_POST['businessPhone'],
     "businessWebsite" => $_POST['businessWebsite'],
     "businessAddress" => $_POST['businessAddress'],
     "businessAddress2" => $_POST['businessAddress2'],
     "businessCity" => $_POST['businessCity'],
     "businessState" => $_POST['businessState'],
     "businessZip" => $_POST['businessZip']
), array(
    'AND' => array(
        "clientId" => $_POST['clientId'],
        "businessCity" => $_POST['businessCity'],
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$datas = $db->update( "meta" , ["metalabel"=>$label[0][0]], ["AND"=>["metakey"=>"Collection", "metavalue"=>$_POST["metavalue"]] ]  );
```

you must set an array with logic operator (AND or OR) and as the first value of this you must set another array...see my example above